# Not able to split a string in perl - getting unmatched ( in regex; marked by (-- Here in m/ error

Tags: perl, split

The below is my code

```
$var = '            "jjjjjjjj&Q_30006_47=540IT%20(540%2FOR%2FHPSC%2FD%2F02%2F11&Q_30006_4=&Q_30006_6=12&Q_30006_7=&Q_30006_" &';

($temp1,$temp2) = split($var,"&");

print $temp1;
```

I need to get 
$temp1 =            "jjjjjjjj
and
$temp2 as the remaining part of the string after the first &.

I am getting error because of the '(' in the string.

Can anyone please advise on how to split this.
Thanks!!

Comment: In the future you should first consult the manual (perldoc.perl.org) if you're not sure how to use a specific function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you have the parameter orders wrong.  The pattern should be first:

```
($temp1,$temp2) = split("&", $var);
```

However, that will split on all `&` characters.  You probably are looking for this (the 2 is the limit):

```
($temp1,$temp2) = split("&", $var, 2);
```

Comment: Yes, I am wrong in the way I invoked the split function. Thanks, your code worked!!

Comment: I prefer to write it `split( /&/, $var )` as a reminder that that first parameter is a regex (and things like `split("?", $var)` will error out)

Answer (score 2):

```
($temp1,$temp2) = split '&', $var, 2;
```